# converting List<String> to List<mytype>

Tags: java

I have written a java program to read lines from an xml using buffered reader. This xml contains questions, multiple choice and answers. These questions, choices, answers are stored in `List<String>`. While presenting these questions to the user, the program requires `List<Question>`. I clearly understand that a list of `String` type cannot be copied into list of `Question` type. So, how do I do this? and what concept am I missing?

EDIT:

I think `List<Integer>` to `List<String>` or viz., is different to my question because `.toString()` and `.parseInt()` methods exist.

Comment: Please provide the class of your custom type

Answer (score 2):

The two types:

```
List<String>
```

and:

```
List<myType>
```

are effectively two completely different types.

Also note:

```
List
```

Is the same as

```
List<Object>
```

So generally the conversion from List to List needs to be done the hard way:

```
for(String element : listOfStrings ) {
 MyType myType = doStuffToCreateMyType( element );
 myTypeList.add( myType );
}
```

Let's say for example "MyType" is String and the other type is "Date", then an example conversion could be:

```
private String doStuffToCreateMyType(Date input) {
      DateFormatter f = ....
      return f.format(input); 
         // or perhaps could simply do: return input.toString();
}
```

Also to mention, Java will try to auto convert elements for you if the types can be down-casted. So you should be able to do this:

```
List<MyType> myTypeList = ...;
List<Object> myObjectList = (List<Object>) myTypeList;
```

Also note, if you try to case an object into String, Java will automatically call Object.toString() to do the cast for you. The compiler likely won't be smart enough to do that for pair-wise elements of two lists, but it is something to watch out for when casting object types.

Comment: Thanks a heap. I think I understand but I'm still missing something obvious. Could you please elaborate doStuffToCreateMyType(element) method.

Comment: That is really dependent on your input. You will probably have to include a sample xml file if you really need somebody to figure out that method.

Comment: Updated to give an example - as matt stated, the exact conversion would depend on the object types you have.